# Draw waveform from audio data

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine

In Unity 3d, I'm trying to draw the waveform of an attached audio file (without having to play the audio). After a while I realised that the numbers I was getting from GetData were mainly zeros and the occasional Epsilon values. I've had a quick google and othersseem to experience the same thing.

Can someone with a better understanding of audio in Unity point out if I am going hideously wrong somewhere. However, if it is a Unity bug; is there a workaround??

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CheckGetData : MonoBehaviour
{

    public AudioClip theSound;

    void Start()
    {
        audio.clip = theSound;

        int numOfSamples = audio.clip.samples;   // 1647360
        float[] samples = new float[numOfSamples];

        audio.clip.GetData(samples, 0); //left channel
        for (int i= 0; i < samples.Length; i++)
        {
            print(samples[i])

            // 0 UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:print(Object) 887 times
            // -6.103516E-05
            // -0.0001220703
            // 6.103516E-05 etc...

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you only looking at 1024 samples? Why not get the full data? Values are between -1 and 1 if I'm not mistaken. So small values are not a surprise at all. And only looking at 1024 samples (out of 1647360? Or times 2 for 2 channels) is not all that significant.

Comment: That was just me being cautious. I have had a couple of crashes in unity where the scene wouldn't play, just hang and crash. I'll edit the code.

Comment: Just find the maximum and minimum values. If those are still insignificant and you do have a fair bit of audio in there, then there might be something going on.